# when try to run something, permission denied on mac terminal

Tags: macos, gcc, command-line, terminal, macos-mojave

i compiled a c code and when I try to run it with `./` command, it gives me `-bash: ./hw : Permission denied .`
please help me.
note : i use Mac os Mojave.

**C code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    fscanf(ptr,"%d", &n);
    printf("%d",n);
    fclose(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

**Compile command:**

```
gcc -c hw.c -o hw
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the command `chmod +x hw`. This will changes the permissions on the file to allow execution. You should then be able to run it with `./`

Comment: now the error is `-bash: ./hw: cannot execute binary file`

Comment: How are you compiling the program?

Comment: `gcc -c hw.c -o hw`
the code is : 
`#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    fscanf(ptr,"%d", &n);
    printf("%d",n);
    fclose(ptr);
    return 0;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

you are just creating an object file (.o) not an executable.

try compiling with

```
gcc hw.c -o hw
```